# How to see if a checkbox is selected?

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic, field-pack, pt-checkboxes

I'm using P&T Fieldpack (2.1.1), EE 2.9.2 and Matrix 2.6. I have a column in my Matrix field that has 2 checkboxes: "text" and "picture".

If only the "text" checkbox is checked then this works to determine that:

```
{if my_matrix_column == "text"}popup{/if}
```

But if both are checked, that never returns true. So I try this:

```
{if '{my_matrix_column:selected option="text"}'}popup{/if}
```

and that resolves to true every time - even if nothing at all is checked.

So, any ideas on how I can tell if the "text" checkbox is selected no matter if the "picture" checkbox is selected or not?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem post upgrade from EE 2.8 to 2.10 and found that I needed to change the conditionals as follows to make them work again:

```
{if '{my_checkboxes:selected option="value"}' == '1'}
```

Comment: Second this solution for EE 2.9+ (at least) ... seems to strictly evaluate the truthy value of 1, probably because it's enclosed in quotes. Removing the quotes doesn't work, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

```
{if '{my_matrix_column:selected option="text"}'}popup{/if}
```

This should definitely work, according to the Field Pack docs.

You could also just loop through and do your conditional inside the loop:

```
{my_matrix_column}
    {if option == "text"}popup{/option}
{my_matrix_column}
```

Comment: yep - it should work and it did work but after I upgraded to EE 2.9, it doesn't work. I'll try the loop.

Comment: using the loop didn't work either.

Comment: did you end up coming up with a solution for this? I'm having the same issue but with P&T checkboxes using the :selected conditional...